# find a specific string pattern from a file in Unix Shell Scripting

Tags: shell-script

I have the below command.

```
 unzip -p GLP.K4C.S06F5.BG57218-rdf.zip | grep  ":taxonomies-" | head -1
```

which gives me the output as,

```
    <j.2:Taxo_Version rdf:resource="refmat:taxonomies-8.2.0"/>
```

However, I need to extract only **taxonomies-8.2.0** instead of full string as above.

Comment: In the future, please provide an example of your input file, it lets us give you more specific answers than just a single line. For example, my solutions below might work for other lines of your file but I can't know since you haven't shown it.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use grep's `-o` option, combined with the power of [PCREs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) (`-P`):

```
   -o, --only-matching
          Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
          with each such part on a separate output line.
   -P, --perl-regexp
          Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  Perl  regular  expression  (PCRE, see
          below).  This is highly experimental and grep  -P  may  warn  of
          unimplemented features.
```

So, you could do

```
 unzip -p GLP.K4C.S06F5.BG57218-rdf.zip | grep -oP ':\Ktaxonomies-[^"]*' | head -1
```

The `\K` causes anything matched up to that point to be ignored (so the `:` is not printed) and `[^"]*"` means "match as many non-`"` characters as possible.

Other options include:

1. `sed`

   ```
   unzip -p GLP.K4C.S06F5.BG57218-rdf.zip | 
       sed -n 's/.*:\(taxonomies-[^"]*\).*/\1/p' | head -1
   ```

   The `-n` causes `sed` to print nothing unless explicitly told to and the `s///` is the substitution operator. It will replace everything on the line with the part of the line between the parentheses (`\1`). The `p` causes the resulting line to be printed.
2. Perl

   ```
   unzip -p GLP.K4C.S06F5.BG57218-rdf.zip | 
     perl -lne 's/.*:(taxonomies-[^"]).*/$1/ && print' | head -1
   ```

   The same basic idea as the `sed`. If the substitution was successful, the line is printed. An alternative would be

   ```
   unzip -p GLP.K4C.S06F5.BG57218-rdf.zip | 
     perl -lne '/.*:(taxonomies-[^"])/ && print $1' | head -1
   ```

Comment: Still not getting expected output. This will give you correct output [cpc22776 141029_134901]$ unzip -p GLP.K4C.S1BB7.BG49087-rdf.zip | sed -n 's/.*:\(taxonomies-[^"].\).*/\1/p' | head -1
taxonomies-07 but when it has taxonomy verison it prints . after 8---- cpclb2a670:/usr/local/afs7/PaF/LNK4C/C2B_75/LN_input/zip_processed/0KFQ/FRA-DEV_176YYY-K4C_28Oct/141029_062955_load $ unzip -p GLP.K4C.S0700.BG75448-rdf.zip | sed -n 's/.*:\(taxonomies-[^"].\).*/\1/p' | head -1
taxonomies-8.

Comment: @AtilThakor yes, that's why I said you need to show your inout file. Please [edit] your question and add an example of your file.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the occurence of **:** character in your input, you could do something like this.

```
echo " <j.2:Taxo_Version rdf:resource="refmat:taxonomies-8.2.0"/>" | 
awk -F\: '{print $4}' | sed 's/..$//'
```

The `awk` command prints the 4<sup>th</sup> string after the **:** delimiter and the `sed` command is used to remove the last 2 characters to get the desired output.

However, if this method works or not depends on your input as [terdon points out in his comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163408/find-a-specific-string-pattern-from-a-file-in-unix-shell-scripting/163410#comment267927_163408).

**EDIT**

The final pipe to `sed` could very well be avoided if we use the solution as suggested by [jasonwryan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6761/jasonwryan)  in [the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163408/find-a-specific-string-pattern-from-a-file-in-unix-shell-scripting/163410?noredirect=1#comment267958_163410). So, the command would effectively be rephrased as,

```
 echo " <j.2:Taxo_Version rdf:resource="refmat:taxonomies-8.2.0"/>" | 
 awk -F: '{sub(/\/>/,""); print $4}'
```

Another solution just using cut and rev can be framed as,

```
echo " <j.2:Taxo_Version rdf:resource="refmat:taxonomies-8.2.0"/>" | 
cut -d ':' -f4 | rev | cut -c 3- | rev
```

Again the specifying of delimiter is dependent on the input file and from the example you have provided the characters that I need to extract occur after the 4<sup>th</sup> position of the delimiter. I use `cut` to extract the substring after this 4<sup>th</sup> delimiter and use good old `rev` technique to reverse the string and remove the last 3 characters and again apply `rev` on it to get the actual string.

Comment: ...or split fields on two delimiters (`-F"[:"]`) or use `gsub` to avoid the pipe to `sed`.

Comment: @jasonwryan, Thanks. But, I am afraid I am not following your suggestion. Could you please let me know how I could improve the command further?

Comment: @jasonwryan, added another example without using `awk` or `sed`. Hope this one is little better.

Comment: Either of these will work (and don't require another process): `awk -F: '{sub(/\/>/,""); print $4}'` or `awk -F'[:/]' '{print $4}'`: let Awk do the lifting... :)

Comment: @jasonwryan, thanks a lot. I added your suggestion to the answer. :)